# On Shannon Capacity

Tags: graphs, information-theory

Let $G$ be a graph whose Shannon Capacity is $\Theta(G)$. Is there any graph product for which the Shannon Capacity is $\Theta(G)^k$ where $k$ is the number of times the product is taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shannon capacity is defined as
$$ \Theta(G) = \sup_k \alpha(G^k)^{1/k}, $$
where $G^k$ is the [strong graph product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_graph_product). It is not hard to show that $\alpha(G^{k+l}) \geq \alpha(G^k) \alpha(G^l)$, and this implies that $\alpha(G^k)^{1/k}$ converges. Therefore
$$ \Theta(G) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \alpha(G^k)^{1/k} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \alpha(G^{tk})^{1/{tk}} = \Theta(G^t)^{1/t}. $$